# arbitrary sequences in "zipped" sequences (mapped sequences actually)

Tags: python, list, tuples, map-function

This works nicely:

```
In [53]: map(None, a,c,d)
Out[53]: [(1, 4, 'a'), (2, 5, 'b'), (3, 6, None), (None, 7, None)]
```

(

```
In [60]: a
Out[60]: [1, 2, 3]

In [61]: c
Out[61]: [4, 5, 6, 7]

In [62]: d
Out[62]: ['a', 'b']
```

)

But if I want lists instead of tuples it fails:

```
In [54]: map(list, a,c,d)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-9447da50383e> in <module>()
----> 1 map(list, a,c,d)

TypeError: list() takes at most 1 argument (3 given)
```

I can get around this by:

```
In [58]: [list(x) for x in map(None, a, c, d)]
Out[58]: [[1, 4, 'a'], [2, 5, 'b'], [3, 6, None], [None, 7, None]]
```

But is there smth that I could use in map() directly?

It seems that most sequences have this problem:

```
In [59]: tuple(3,3,5)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-f396cf5fe9be> in <module>()
----> 1 tuple(3,3,5)

TypeError: tuple() takes at most 1 argument (3 given)
```

I'd like to be able to pass a peculiar sequence to map() and get a list of such sequences (such as lists, sets, etc) combining subsequent elems from "zipped" (mapped) sequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> [list(x) for x in itertools.izip_longest([1,2,3],[4,5,6,7],['a','b'])]
[[1, 4, 'a'], [2, 5, 'b'], [3, 6, None], [None, 7, None]]
```

Comment: what I also like about this solution is that there's fillvalue= kw argument to izip_longest

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
map(list, map(None, a, c, d))
```

Since `map(None, ...)` is equivalent to `itertools.izip_longest(...)`..
This is better (in 2.x at least) :

```
map(list, itertools.izip_longest(a, c, d))
```

Here are some examples..

```
In [100]: zip(a,c,d)
Out[100]: [(1, 4, 'a'), (2, 5, 'b')]

In [101]: map(None, a,c,d)
Out[101]:[(1, 4, 'a'), (2, 5, 'b'), (3, 6, None), (None, 7, None)]

In [102]: map(list, map(None, a,c,d))
Out[102]:[[1, 4, 'a'], [2, 5, 'b'], [3, 6, None], [None, 7, None]]

In [103]: import itertools
In [104]: map(list, itertools.izip_longest(a,c,d))
Out[104]:[[1, 4, 'a'], [2, 5, 'b'], [3, 6, None], [None, 7, None]]
```

Also, it seems you don't understand how to use `tuple` & `list`:
These 2 function-like objects take an iterable and convert them to a `tuple` & `list` respectively.

```
>>> range(10)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> tuple(range(10))
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
>>> list(tuple(range(10)))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

You usually use the [`zip()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to zip lists; your use of `map()` is a happy side-effect of how that function works.

`zip()` still produces tuples, but you can combine *that* with `map()`:

```
map(list, zip(a, c, d))
```

or you can use a list comprehension (slower but more flexibility when filtering, nesting loops and transforming the data):

```
[list(t) for t in zip(a, c, d)]
```

Comment: I did not write explicitly I need to make all values from the longest sequence and substitute smth else (like None) for missing values in shorter sequences, hence zip() is not useful since it truncates resulting sequence to the length of the shortest sequence.